# How to set checkstate of particular item in repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit which is bound to datasource?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm having `repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit` which is placed in `BarEditItem`. I want to bind a datasource to the `repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit`.

For that I used the `datasource` property of `repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit`. But I'm unable to set the `checkstate` to checked or unchecked in the datasource for each item in `datasource`. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What datasoource are you binding to? Some code will be helpful. Here is an idea

```
// Add check items to the control's dropdown.
string[] itemValues = new string[] { 
    "Circle", "Rectangle", "Ellipse", 
    "Triangle", "Square" };
foreach (string value in itemValues)
    checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Add(value, CheckState.Unchecked, true);
// Specify the separator character.
checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.SeparatorChar = ';';
// Set the edit value.
checkedComboBoxEdit1.SetEditValue("Circle; Ellipse");
// Disable the Circle item.
checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items["Circle"].Enabled = false;
```

[RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.Items](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit_Itemstopic) Property

Basically you need to set the SetEditValue